# Scanning ASCII value of each character of a string

Tags: c++, c, string, ascii

Is there anyway , if I enter any string , then I want to scan ASCII value of each character inside that string , if I enter "john" then I should get 4 variables getting ASCII value of each character, in C or C++

Comment: Better make sure you run it on an ASCII machine if you want to do it the easy way.

Comment: In the raw binary executable, there is no such thing as strings. All characters in memory are merely integer numbers. Simply print a character as you would print an integer, and you will get its ASCII value.

Comment: @Lundin if I were to print a character as I usually print an int in C++, I would not get the ASCII value, because there's an overload of ``ostream& operator<<` for `char`. So, although easy to achieve, it isn't as simple as that.

Comment: @chris: I don't think anyone these days needs to make sure they're using an ASCII machine.  Non-ASCII machines are truly rare, if you have one, you already know.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, Sure, but you never know what people you distribute your program to use. Of course just this would most likely not be distributed, but awareness is good. I'm just pedantic on the things that have a slight, but still existing possibility.

Comment: @juanchopanza You would print an integer with `cout << some_int`, not with `cout << some_char`. So you will need to simply typecast it to an int. `cout << (int)some_char`, or if you prefer: `cout << static_cast<int>(some_char)`.

Comment: @chris: It's a slight, but existing probability that you'll win the lottery even though you didn't buy any tickets.  EBCDIC systems are that rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah it's very easy ..just a demo

```
int main()
{
 char *s="hello";
 while(*s!='\0')
  {
  printf("%c --> %d\n",*s,*s);
  s++;
  }
 return 0;
}
```

But make sure your machine is supporting the ASCII value format.
In C every char has one integral value associted with it called ASCII.
Using `%d` format specifier you can directly print the ASCII of any char as above.

NOTE: It's better to get good book and practice this kind of program yourself.

Comment: This is why you should always use {} after statements. Bug on line 6, s++ is outside the loop.

Comment: I love the "But make sure your machine is supporting the ASCII value format."   I think the folks running EBCDIC know who they are, thank you very much (ignoring here minor incompatibilities, like the JIS `¥ = \\` bit).

Comment: @DietrichEpp - yes, folks running EBCDIC systems know who they are, but that's not the point. If the **requirement** is to display ASCII codes (which is what the question asks for), ignoring EBCDIC systems doesn't satisfy the requirements. If the requirement is to display whatever code point represents a given character, then systems that use ASCII and systems that use EBCDIC will show different results.

Comment: Amazing how this accepted answer completely fails to answer the question posed. Not saying the answer isn't good, it clearly is. But it's a great demonstration of how newbies are unable to ask the question they mean to ask.

Comment: Uhm... You cannot have non-constant pointer to a string literal... Too much DOS programming or something?

Answer (score 10):

Given a string in C:

```
char s[] = "john";
```

or in C++:

```
std::string s = "john";
```

`s[0]` gives the numeric value of the first character, `s[1]` the second an so on.

If your computer uses an ASCII representation of characters (which it does, unless it's something very unusual), then these values are the ASCII codes. You can display these values numerically:

```
printf("%d", s[0]);                     // in C
std::cout << static_cast<int>(s[0]);    // in C++
```

Being an integer type (`char`), you can also assign these values to variables and perform arithmetic on them, if that's what you want.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "scan". If you're asking how to iterate over the string to process each character in turn, then in C it's:

```
for (char const * p = s; *p; ++p) {
    // Do something with the character value *p
}
```

and in (modern) C++:

```
for (char c : s) {
    // Do something with the character value c
}
```

If you're asking how to read the string as a line of input from the terminal, then in C it's

```
char s[SOME_SIZE_YOU_HOPE_IS_LARGE_ENOUGH];
fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
```

and in C++ it's

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;  // if you want a single word
std::getline(std::cin, s); // if you want a whole line
```

If you mean something else by "scan", then please clarify.

Comment: printf("%d", s[0]);                     // in C
than it will only gives me the ascii of 'j' .i want to scan the value of j to a variable , then increment , than 'o' to variable and then again increment

Comment: @l4zyw0rm: That's `char c = s[0]; ++c;`. You can increment character values just like any other numeric type.

Comment: but its just printing the ascii's , anyway to scan these values ?

Comment: @l4zyw0rm: What do you mean by "scan"? Iterate over the characters in the string? Read them from the console or a file? Or something else?

Comment: @l4zyw0rm: Or do you mean you want to declare a named variable for each character in a string? You can't do that, since the number of variables wouldn't be known. The best you can do is put the characters in an array or string; but they're already in one, so there's no point.

Comment: what i want to do is entering any string and performing any arithmatic operation on the ascii values of each character of the string.

Comment: @l4zyw0rm: OK, my answer should have enough information to do that, in either language. If it's still not clear, then please decide which language you're using, and read a tutorial on that language.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply get the ascii value of a char by casting it to type int:

```
char c = 'b';
int i = c; //i contains ascii value of char 'b'
```

Thus, in your example the code to get the ascii values of a string would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string text = "John";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << (int)text[i] << endl; //prints corresponding ascii values (one per line)
    }
}
```

To get the corresponding char from an integer representing an entry in the ascii table, you just have to cast the int back to char again:

```
char c = (char)74 // c contains 'J'
```

The code given above was written in C++ but it basically works the same way in C (and many other languages as well I guess)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to turn a string of length 'x' into x variables. In  C or C++ you can only declare a fixed number of variables. But probably you don't need to do what you are saying. Perhaps you just need an array, or most likely you just need a better way to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve. If you explain what the problem is in the first place, then I'm sure a better way can be explained.

Comment: There is one exception to this, though. In C++ you actually can do that as long as a string is a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Ya,I think there are some more better solutions are also available but this one also be helpful.
**In C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main(){
  char s[]="abc";
  int cnt=0;
  while(1){
    if(s[cnt++]==NULL)break;
  }
  int *a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*cnt);
  for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)a[i]=s[i];
  for(int i=0;i<cnt-1;i++)printf("%d\n",a[i]);  
  return 0;
}
```

**In C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s="abc";
    //int *a=new int[s.length()];
    //for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)a[i]=s[i];
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    cout<<(int)s[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this one will be helpful..